# How to define the loss function or how to optimize if the target is a set?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow

I use a full-connected network to get the whole words distribution from the last state of an encoder.

For example, there are 5 words in the vocabulary.

```
P = [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0,4]
```

And the ground truth is a words' set for this train data.

I sample 3 words from the 5 words and if the target set contains the 3 words , then I want the probability of the 3 words in `P` increase, for this state.

If one of the 3 word is not in the target set, then I want the probability of the word in `P` decrease, for this state.

So I wrote these code:

```
reward = [0,0,0]
```

Suppose the first 3 words are sampled from `P`, and only the first 2 of the 3 words are in the target set. And the third word is not in the target set. Then

```
reward = [1,1,-1]
```

Then I compute the negative sum and dot product of `reward` and sampled 3 `P2=[0.1, 0.1, 0.2]` as the loss

```
loss = -sum(reward * P2.log())
```

But I fail to get the result: The top probability words can be selected from the vocabulary for every state.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06114v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer from [SQLNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04436)'s equation:

[image: -]